# Java - complex data structure with multiple values and acess data structure with filers

Tags: java, algorithm

I have complex data Object like Stock and it has attributes like region, name, price, volume, high, low...
and i need to maintain this millions of object in data structure such that input will contain query like All stock in this X region and price between A-B and Volumne between P-Q...
So how can i maintain such data ? to get faster response

Comment: Use an in-memory database like H2

Comment: where do the millions of object/data come from? can you do the query on that level?

Comment: You will need to familiarize yourself with the following: SQL, JDBC.

Comment: What about few thousands of data. we will be populating it from file.. and want to access it from java objects rather from DB

Answer (score 1):

Normally you let a database do this for you,
but the algorithmic approach is to use a tree that supports range queries, for example a [kd-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).

Say you have ten parameters for each stock, then you can consider your database to be a set of 10-dimensional points. If you want to find stock with 3 parameters in some ranges, that's a 3 dimensional range query on this set.